# Flask Ansible error to start via supervisor

Tags: python, nginx, supervisord

I'm using the following script:
http://mattupstate.com/python/devops/2012/08/07/flask-wsgi-application-deployment-with-ubuntu-ansible-nginx-supervisor-and-uwsgi.html

I have updated the scripts to the following:
setup_server.yml

```
- name: Install python packages
  hosts: webservers
  user: ubuntu
  sudo: yes
  tasks:
    - name: add nginx ppa
      apt_repository: 
        repo: "ppa:nginx/stable"

    - name: install common packages needed for python application development
      apt: 
        name: "{{ item }}"
      with_items:
        - libpq-dev
        - libmysqlclient-dev
        - libxml2-dev
        - libjpeg62
        - libjpeg62-dev
        - libfreetype6
        - libfreetype6-dev
        - zlib1g-dev
        - mysql-client
        - python-dev
        - python-setuptools
        - python-imaging
        - python-mysqldb
        - python-psycopg2
        - git-core
        - nginx

    - name: install pip
      easy_install: 
        name: pip

    - name: install various libraries with pip
      pip: 
        name: "{{ item }}"
      with_items:
        - virtualenv
        - supervisor
        - uwsgi

    - name: symlink imaging library files
      file: src=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so dest=/usr/lib/libfreetype.so state=link

    - name: symlink imaging library files
      file: src=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so dest=/usr/lib/libz.so state=link

    - name: symlink imaging library files
      file: src=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62 dest=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so state=link

    - name: symlink imaging library files
      file: src=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so dest=/usr/lib/libjpeg.so state=link

    - name: remove default nginx site
      file: path=/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default state=absent

    - name: write nginx.conf
      template: src=templates/nginx.conf dest=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

    - name: create supervisord config folder
      file: dest=/etc/supervisor state=directory owner=root

    - name: create supervisord config
      template: src=templates/supervisord.conf dest=/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf

    - name: create supervisord init script
      template: src=templates/supervisord.sh dest=/etc/init.d/supervisord mode=0755

    - name: start supervisord service and have it run during system startup
      service: name=supervisord state=started enabled=yes

    - name: create webapps directory
      file: dest=/srv/webapps state=directory
```

and:
deploy.yml

```
- name: Setup webser
  hosts: webservers
  user: ubuntu
  sudo: True

  vars:
    app_name: hello_flask
    repo_url: https://github.com/mattupstate/ansible-tutorial.git
    repo_remote: origin
    repo_version: master
    webapps_dir: /srv/webapps
    wsgi_file: wsgi.py
    wsgi_callable: app

  tasks:
    - name: ensure log directory
      file: path={{ webapps_dir }}/{{ app_name }}/log state=directory mode=0755

    - name: deploy code from repository
      synchronize: src=/Users/ankitjain/dev/virel/ansible-tutorial/ dest={{ webapps_dir }}/{{ app_name }}/src archive=yes delete=yes rsync_opts="--exclude='tags' --exclude='.git' --exclude='*.swp'" rsync_path='sudo rsync'

    - name: install dependencies into virtualenv
      pip: requirements={{ webapps_dir }}/{{ app_name }}/src/requirements.txt virtualenv={{ webapps_dir }}/{{ app_name }}/venv state=present

    - name: create supervisor program config
      template: src=templates/supervisor.ini dest=/etc/supervisor/{{ app_name }}.ini
      notify:
        - restart app

    - name: create nginx site config
      template: src=templates/nginx_site.conf dest=/etc/nginx/sites-available/{{ app_name }}.conf
      notify:
        - restart nginx

    - name: link nginx config
      file: src=/etc/nginx/sites-available/{{ app_name }}.conf dest=/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/{{ app_name }}.conf state=link

    - name: start app
      supervisorctl: name={{ app_name }} state=started

  handlers:
    - name: restart app
      supervisorctl: name={{ app_name }} state=restarted

    - name: restart nginx
      service: name=nginx state=restarted
```

I have verified that the source is working fine if I run it locally. It is copied correctly with all the variables. Supervisor is running correctly. So nginx config is set correctly, I'm able to start the webserver it directly.

But the supervisor is not able to start the webserver. I get the following error:
hello_flask: ERROR (abnormal termination)

I'm not sure how to debug this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Log in to the server over SSH
- Use supervisor manually to start the process. Supervisor documentation: http://supervisord.org/
- If needed, handedit supervisor configuration files to make supervisor to output the stdout and stderr a file you can ready to see what error message the application is printing out when started through supervisor

Comment: Thanks I'll try this. I already tried running the command directly and via supervisorctl on the box. It works directly not via supervisord (same command). I'll try to check the stderr logs. Thanks